# pm2 eats cluster logs when using child_process

Tags: node.js, logging, child-process, pm2

I'm using PM2 v.3.2.2

I have a nodejs program composed of 2 script: `main.js` and `child.js`.

- main.js creates a `child_process.fork` of child.js.
- main.js and child.js print some logs using console.log.

If I start the main.js script using `pm2 start main.js` everything works great, I can see both logs.

If I start the main.js script in **cluster mode**, using `pm2 start main.js --name FOO -i 2`, I can only see the main.js' logs.

How can I fix this behaviour? I would like to get both logs printed.